# VirtualBox not install CentOS Guest Additions

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I can't install the Guest Additions on CentOS.

I update `yum update`, `yum update groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

This is my log:

```
Removing existing VirtualBox kernel modules.
Building the main Guest Additions module.
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.1 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.1 -j1 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.1
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest-linux.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest-linux.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest-linux.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuest.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuest.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuest.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibGenericRequest.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibHGCMInternal.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuestR0LibInit.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuestR0LibInit)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuestR0LibInit.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibInit.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibInit.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibInit.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibPhysHeap.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/.VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/.tmp_VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev.o /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/VBoxGuestR0LibVMMDev.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.alloc-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(alloc_r0drv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.tmp_alloc-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.initterm-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(initterm_r0drv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.tmp_initterm-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.memobj-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(memobj_r0drv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.tmp_memobj-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.mpnotification-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(mpnotification_r0drv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.tmp_mpnotification-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o"; fi; fi;
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/.powernotification-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.1/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.1/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be missing `dkms` and/or `kernel-devel`:

```
yum install dkms kernel-devel
```

Alternative: Download VBoxGuestAdditions.iso from [http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.0/) and attach it as a cdrom and run the installer there.

Comment: I do, but not work :/

Comment: Removing installed version 5.2.0 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find out what went wrong
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted